# NIntegrate fails to solve a double oscillatory integral

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, trigonometry, precision-and-accuracy

I need to compute the following integral:

```
NIntegrate[((Sin[a*q1]*Sin[a*q2])/(q1*q2))*(Cos[b*Sqrt[1 + q1^2 + q2^2]]*Cos[x*q1 + y*q2]/(1 + q1^2 + q2^2)), {q1, 0, +Infinity}, {q2, 0, +Infinity}]
```

where a, b are positive real constants and x, y are real positions on the bidimensional plane (I will make them vary and plot the result of this numerical integration as a DensityPlot on the xy-plane for fixed a, b constants).
The integration gives me the following error:

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
```

I've tried to set specific values for WorkingPrecision, MaxPoints and PrecisionGoal, but the integration fails for many (x, y) values and it takes anyway too long to be computed.
Is there a way to solve this error and compute the integral for **all** values of x, y in the range (-40, 40) with a=20, b=10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done as follows, making use of switching to the polar coordinates.

```
a = 10; b = 20; ClearAll[x, y];
f[\[Phi]_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[r*((Sin[a*q1]*Sin[a*q2])/(q1*q2))*(Cos[b*Sqrt[1 + q1^2 + q2^2]]*
  Cos[x*q1 + y*q2]/(1 + q1^2 + q2^2)) /. {q1 -> r*Cos[\[Phi]], 
q2 -> r*Sin[\[Phi]]}, {r, 0, Infinity}]
f[Pi/2 - 0.01, 2, -4]
```

> `-1.19509`

```
NIntegrate[Evaluate[f[\[Phi], 2, -4]], {\[Phi], 0, Pi/2}]
```

> `0.661215`

and a warning (not an error).